# Eight Queens using backtracking and recursion c++

Tags: c++, recursion, boolean, backtracking

I have just learned backtracking and recursion, and have an assignment for using it in the Eight Queens Problem.  I am supposed to prompt the user to enter a row, and then procedure place_next_queen(bool& done) should attempt to place the next queen at the next column.  This procedure is the recursive function, and I believe that's where the problem lies.  Please take a look, any help would be greatly appreciated! And please let me know if you need any more information...
The problem is that the program prints out the 1 correctly in the first column, but the rest of the board is all zeroes.

Here is my class EightQueensProblem:

```
class EightQueensProblem
{
public:
//Default constructor, initializes NUM_QUEENS to 8 in initializer list
EightQueensProblem() : NUM_QUEENS(8){}; 
void clear_board();
void display_board(ostream& os);
bool queen_under_attack(int row, int column);
bool start_game(int row);
private:
static const int CHESSBOARD_SIZE = 8; 
//2D array of int values not on the heap of dimension CHESSBOARD_SIZE x CHESSBOARD_SIZE
int chessboard[CHESSBOARD_SIZE][CHESSBOARD_SIZE];
const int NUM_QUEENS;
//int representing number of queens currently placed on the chessboard
int num_queens_on_board;
void place_queen_on_square(int row, int column);
void remove_queen_from_square(int row, int column);
void place_next_queen(bool& done);
};

void EightQueensProblem::clear_board()
{
//resets all squares on chessboard to value 0
for(int row = 0; row < CHESSBOARD_SIZE; row ++)
{
    for(int column = 0; column < CHESSBOARD_SIZE; column ++)
    {
        chessboard[row][column] = 0;
    }
}
//sets number of queens on board to 0
num_queens_on_board = 0;
}

void EightQueensProblem::display_board(ostream& os)
{
//outputs chessboard to given output stream without changing calling object
for(int row = 0; row < CHESSBOARD_SIZE; row ++)
{
    for(int column = 0; column < CHESSBOARD_SIZE; column++)
    {
        os << chessboard[row][column] << " ";
    }
    os << endl;
}
}

bool EightQueensProblem::queen_under_attack(int row, int column)
{
//detect if a queen occupies a square along the southwest diagonal of square (row, col)
for(int i = 0; (row + i) < CHESSBOARD_SIZE && (column - i) >= 0; i ++)
{
    if(chessboard[row + 1][column - i] != 0)
        return true;
}
//along southeast diagonal
for(int i = 0; (row + i) < CHESSBOARD_SIZE && (column + i) < CHESSBOARD_SIZE; i ++)
{
    if(chessboard[row + i][column + i] != 0)
        return true;
}
//along northwest diagonal
for(int i = 0; (row - i) >= 0 && (column - i) >= 0; i ++)
{
    if(chessboard[row - i][column - i] != 0)
        return true;
}
//along northeast diagonal
for(int i = 0; (row - i) >= 0 && (column + i) < CHESSBOARD_SIZE; i ++)
{
    if(chessboard[row - i][column + i] != 0)
        return true;
}
//along same row
for(int i = 0; i < CHESSBOARD_SIZE; i ++)
{
    if(chessboard[row][i] != 0)
        return true;
}
//along same column
for(int i = 0; i < CHESSBOARD_SIZE; i ++)
{
    if(chessboard[i][column] != 0)
        return true;
}
return false;
}

bool EightQueensProblem::start_game(int row)
{
//places the first queen at the given row in the left most column
chessboard[row][0] = 1;
    num_queens_on_board = 1;
bool done;
place_next_queen(done);
if(done == true)
    return true;
else
    return false;
}

void EightQueensProblem::place_queen_on_square(int row, int column)
{
//places a queen on the board at the given location (row, column)
chessboard[row][column] = column + 1;
    num_queens_on_board++;
}

void EightQueensProblem::remove_queen_from_square(int row, int column)
{
//removes a queen from the board at the given location (row, column)
chessboard[row][column] = 0;
    num_queens_on_board--;
}

void EightQueensProblem::place_next_queen(bool& done)
{
if(num_queens_on_board == NUM_QUEENS)
{
    done = true;
}
else
{
    done = false;
    for(int row = 0; row < (num_queens_on_board - 1); row ++)
{
    if(!queen_under_attack(row, num_queens_on_board))
    {
        place_queen_on_square(row, num_queens_on_board);
        place_next_queen(done);
    }
    else
    {
        remove_queen_from_square(row, num_queens_on_board);
        row ++;
        place_queen_on_square(row, num_queens_on_board);
        place_next_queen(done);
    }
}
    }
    }
```

Here is my main function:

```
int main()
{
cout << "Position the first queen on the chessboard:" << endl << endl;
cout << "Enter the row for the first queen (from 1 to 8): ";
int input_row;
cin >> input_row;
cout << "From the position (" << input_row << ", 1), the EightQueensProblem has solution: " << endl << endl;

EightQueensProblem game;
game.clear_board();
game.start_game(input_row);
game.display_board(cout);
string TargetFileName = "Solutions.txt";
ofstream out(TargetFileName);
game.display_board(out);
out.close();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: So, what's the question? Where is your program failing? Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Oh, the problem is that the program prints out the 1 correctly in the first column, but the rest of the board is all zeroes.

Comment: I'm curious on your main function, as the entire thing is just crashing for me.

Comment: David, I have added my main function.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a solution, but it's too long for a comment. I will edit it after the concerns have been addressed.

How this works at all is beyond me. I've directly copied your code, save the main function, which is:

```
int main() {
    EightQueensProblem e;

    e.clear_board();
    e.start_game(1);
    e.display_board(cout);
}
```

1. The game is started by placing a queen on the board
2. Call place next queen
3. `num_queens_on_board`, never being changed, is still 0
4. `queen_under_attack` returns true (always)
5. The previously placed queen is removed (why?)
6. A new one is palced
7. Repeat 2-7

In a slight bit of irony, since the recursion follows those same steps, it never stops, and I'm getting a StackOverflow. I think you need to step through your logic, (easist to do with a debugger) and fix where you're going wrong.

Comment: I've realized a couple things got omitted when I copied and pasted the code, trying to format it correctly.  Sorry.  I have edited it so now num_queens_on_board is supposed to change.  Please use this new code.
queen_under_attack was not supposed to return true... am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Also, the reason why I removed the previously placed queen is because I'm trying to backtrack.  Probably doing it wrong?  Am I able to omit that part all together and it is implied that the queen will be removed?

Comment: I would think it would be easier to only place something once you find something that is open, and not place, remove, place, remove. Have you tried using a debugger to step through your code?